# Using sed to find/replace doesn't work on whole text file

Tags: macos, sed, applescript

I'm trying to use sed in AppleScript to clean up a text file that has multiple lines.

Source file (test.txt)

```
Some random text

<html>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet rhoncus
</html>

Even more random text
```

Applescript

```
do shell script "sed 's/.*\\(<html.*html>\\).*/\\1/' test.txt"
```

Desired output:

```
<html>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet rhoncus
</html>
```

Received output is unchanged since sed is only looking line by line. Is there a way to force sed to look at the whole file instead?

Comment: Do you know that `<html>` and `</html>` are always going to be alone on a line each?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^<html>/,/^<\/html>/p' file
```

Use seds grep-like option `-n` to turn off automatic printing, then use a range and only print lines within the range.

Alternatively:

```
sed '/^<html>/,/<\/html>/!d' file
```

Comment: These both yield the correct desired output given in the OP, however the forward slash / before the `html>/` part needs to be double escaped \\ in both examples when used in AppleScripts `do shell script ...` command. For example: `do shell script "sed -n '/^<html>/,/^<\\/html>/p' /Users/userName/path/to/test.txt"` and `do shell script "sed '/^<html>/,/<\\/html>/!d' /Users/userName/path/to/test.txt"` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with `awk` then following may help you here too.

```
awk '/<html>/,/<\/html>/' Input_file
```

Comment: This yields the correct desired output given in the OP, however the forward slash / before the `html>/` part needs to be double escaped \\ when used in AppleScripts `do shell script ...` command. For example: `do shell script "awk '/<html>/,/<\\/html>/' /Users/userName/path/to/test.txt"`